# imagettftext function into a function

Tags: php, wordpress, gdlib

So I'm trying to use the GD Library into my Wordpress website.

I've created the images.php page with this code :

```
function loadImage($name, $lastname) {

    header ("Content-type: image/jpg");

$fond = imagecreatefromjpeg('link');

$font = "arial.ttf";
$noir  = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);
$blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 255, 255, 255);


imagettftext($fond, 20, 0, 600, 80, $blanc, $font, $name);
imagestring($fond, 5, 200, 200, $lastname, $blanc);
imagejpeg($fond, 'folder');
}
```

Then I execute loadImage("bob"); into another page. The imagestring function works, but not the imagettftexte. I tried everything but it seems that imagettftext doesnt work when giving args for the string to display.

If you guys could help me on that...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done all but just need to change color something like:

```
$fond = imagecreatefromjpeg('link_of_image');

$font = "arial.ttf";
$noir  = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);
$blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);

imagettftext($fond, 20, 0, 600, 80, $blanc, $font, $name);

imagestring($fond, 5, 200, 200, $lastname, $blanc);

header ("Content-type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg($fond);
imagedestroy($fond);
```

Due to white color it not display.

Comment: that doesnt change anything... It just display the image without any text.

Comment: imagecolorallocate ( resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue )
so, $blanc is black in your code, $noir is white 
so it may be your image may dark so you cant see the text. try light colored image in your code.

Comment: no, $blanc is white in my code : $blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 255, 255, 255);

Comment: so try $blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);
I think you should also remove image name if you not required. If required you to give it fixed to img tag.

Comment: The color is not the issue, it really isn't as I tried with imagestring on the same x and y and it this case it works, but not with imagettftext...

Comment: It actual work for me I have tried something like this..
<?php
function loadImage($name="pranav", $lastname="bhatt") {
$fond = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost/test/images/comment_form.jpg');
$font = "arial.ttf";
$noir  = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);
$blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 250, 55, 55);
imagettftext($fond, 20, 0, 35, 55, $blanc, $font, $name);
//imagestring($fond, 5, 0, 0, $name." ".$lastname, $blanc);
header ("Content-type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg($fond);
imagedestroy($fond);
}
loadImage();
?>

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code and now it's run, only minor change in parameter of **imagettftext**.

> imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x ,
>   int $y , int $color , string $fontfile , string $text )

```
<?php 

    $name='anand';
    $lastname='jain';
    $fond = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/94/Salisbury_mascotlogo.jpg');

    $font = "arial.ttf";
    $noir  = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);
    $blanc = imagecolorallocate($fond, 0, 0, 0);


    imagestring($fond, 5, 200, 200, $lastname, $blanc);
    imagettftext($fond, 12, 0, 100, 127, $noir, $font, $name);


    header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($fond);
    imagedestroy($fond);

    ?>
```